# how to compress data in producers when using spring kafka

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am currently sending data using spring-kafka like this:

```java
val json = objectWriter.writeValueAsString(obj)
kafkaTemplate.send(topic, json)
```

How do i tell KafkaTemplate to use compress the json using snappy before sending?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In apache kafka there is producer config `compression.type` with valid values

> The compression type for all data generated by the producer. The default is none (i.e. no compression). **Valid values are none, gzip, snappy, lz4, or zstd**

So you can set in producer configs

```
ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG "snappy"
```

or by using properties

```
spring.kafka.producer.compression-type= # Compression type for all data generated by the producer.
```

Comment: where does this configuration go? in application.properties??

Comment: you can add it in `application.properties` if you enable auto configuration, show the config @pdeva

Comment: i see. what about the `ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG` (if i dont want to use the application.properties). obviously thats to be added in the java code, but where?

Comment: like this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/spring-kafka/src/test/kotlin/org/springframework/kafka/listener/EnableKafkaKotlinTests.kt @pdeva

Answer (score 1):

**1.) Compression at broker level.**

You can start your zookeeper server with --config compression.type=gzip at the end of the command or you can add this property in zookeeper config file.

**2.) Compression at producer level**

Set the property compression.type = gzip in config/producer.properties of your producer or start your producer with below property

--compression-codec                      'gzip', 'snappy', 'lz4', or 'zstd'.
                                           If specified without value, then it
                                           defaults to 'gzip'